# SQL query pulling incorrect values

Tags: sql

My SQL query is pulling incorrect data, I am sure I setup my query incorrectly. **My query is below:**

```
WITH cte1 AS
    (

    SELECT
    o.PartNo
    , o.JobNo
    , po.PONum
    , cast(po.DateEnt as DATE) as DateEnt
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.JobNo ORDER BY po.PONum DESC) as RowNum

    FROM
        OrderDet as o

    INNER JOIN PODet as pod
        ON o.PartNo = pod.PartNo

    INNER JOIN PO as po
        ON pod.PONum = po.PONum

    WHERE
        o.PartNo = '1234'

    GROUP BY
        po.PONum
        , po.DateEnt
        , o.PartNo
        , o.JobNo

    )

SELECT *
FROM cte1
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

**Sample results are below:**

```
+--------+-------+-------+-----------+
| PartNo | JobNo | PONum |  DateEnt  |
+--------+-------+-------+-----------+
|   1234 |     1 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
|   1234 |     2 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
|   1234 |     3 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
|   1234 |     4 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
|   1234 |     5 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
|   1234 |     6 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
|   1234 |     7 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
|   1234 |     8 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
|   1234 |     9 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
+--------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

The issue is, there are only 4 `JobNos` on `PONum` 20 for `PartNo` 1234.

**The actual results should read:**

```
+--------+-------+-------+-----------+
| PartNo | JobNo | PONum |  DateEnt  |
+--------+-------+-------+-----------+
|   1234 |     3 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
|   1234 |     4 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
|   1234 |     7 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
|   1234 |     9 |    20 | 3/30/2017 |
+--------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

There are 9 `JobNos` total on `PartNo` 1234 ever, but on earlier `PONums.`And my query seems to be pulling ALL `JobNos` and applying the most recent `PONum` to it and displaying the result. `JobNos` 1,2,5,6,8 have nothing to do with `PONum` 20 and have never been applied to it.

Comment: You should post the sample data from each table instead of from the query. It seems like you are missing a column to maybe join on which is resulting in more rows being returned...but I'm just guessing because it's not totally clear.

Comment: There are 20+ columns in each of the tables for the sample data. I could get you some, but not enough to really paint the picture of the table unfortunately.

Comment: How about just the columns that would matter most, including the PK on the tables, the columns you need to return, etc.  A few more details would be helpful in figuring out the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add partno to your partition maybe. Try this: , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.JobNo, o.PartNo ORDER BY po.PONum DESC) as RowNum

Comment: What is the logic for not getting '1,2,5,6,8' in the final result?

Comment: @JacobH Thank you for your input, I tried and it did not work. :/

Comment: Why it needs to select '3,4,7,9'?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy PONum as for Purchase Orders made for that JobNo for certain orders. If all are listed, an inaccurate representation of the data is presented. `1,2,5,6,8` are actually on closed orders.

Comment: Can you provide status of 'Open' or 'Closed' in the sample results?

Comment: @ollie I am working to try and get you some sample data for the tables used.

Comment: @KannanKandasamy you actually just answered my question. Thank you! I did not have the `WHERE` clause stating `OrderStatus` = 'Open'

Comment: @ollie my question was answered, thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Just add your condition at end of your query

```
 AND OrderStatus = 'Open'
```

Comment: I had to add it to the inner query